# meta-programming: inherit from every class in a boost mpl::vector

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-mpl

I wish to inherit from a set of classes contained in a boost mpl::vector.  Is this possible?

Specifically, I wish to extend `test` for arbitrary many template parameters, passed as a mpl::vector.

```
template<class T>
struct Slice
{
public:
  virtual void foo(T v) const = 0;
};

struct A{};
struct B{};

template <class T1, class T2>
struct test : public Slice<T1>, public Slice<T2>
{
  void foo(T1 a) const {std::cout<<"A"<<std::endl;}
  void foo(T2 b) const {std::cout<<"B"<<std::endl;}
};
```

If I know there are only two parameters then I can simply write:

```
template <class mpl_vector_t >
struct test : public Slice<typename mpl::at<mpl_vector_t,mpl::int_<0> >::type >, 
          public Slice<typename mpl::at<mpl_vector_t,mpl::int_<1> >::type >
{
  typedef typename mpl::at<mpl_vector_t,mpl::int_<0> >::type T1;
  typedef typename mpl::at<mpl_vector_t,mpl::int_<1> >::type T2;

  void foo(T1 a) const {std::cout<<"A"<<std::endl;}
  void foo(T2 b) const {std::cout<<"B"<<std::endl;}
};
```

Is is possible to do this for an arbitrary mpl::vector?

My test program looks like so:

```
int
main  (int ac, char **av)
{
  A a;
  B b;
  // test<A,B> t; //original
  test<mpl::vector<A,B> > t;  //mpl::vector with 2 elements
  Slice<A>* Sa = &t;
  Slice<B>* Sb = &t;
  Sa->foo(a);
  Sb->foo(b);
}
```

Comment: interface inheritance, single inheritance, multiple inheritance, _promiscuous_ inheritance :) If only the designers of ATL had had TMP/mpl :_)

Comment: @sehe Nice, I will be adding "promiscuous inheritance" to my vocabulary :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [mpl::inherit_linearly](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/inherit-linearly.html)